# Help making the DARP example run

Tags: routing, pgrouting

I've compiled and installed DARP branch. Is there any data example to test it?.

I've used some data based on document instructions http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/darp.html but no results return.

- What's the difference between depot_id and depot_point_is?
- In distance query i don't understand fields from_order and to_order.
- If i add a request for going from point A to point B, is necesary to add in distances table the cost of going from point B to point A?.
- The field values in distances query, what time units should be?, minutes?, seconds?, miliseconds?.
- Where do darp.c and darp_solver.c leave log messages?.

I know that maybe darp branch is a RC version, but please could you help me with this?.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone, i'll give it a try with the author to see what's happening.

Comment: Please keep us posted, this looks like an interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

You know what they say about being on the bleeding edge of technology ;-)

Looking through the branch, it looks like its fairly rough at the moment and doesn't have documentation or other refinements which would make the code telegraphic. The [core C code](https://github.com/dkastl/pgrouting/blob/darp/extra/darp/src/darp.c) does have a couple of things that may be helpful: it currently has all debugging commented out, if you enable the commenting consistently throughout the code and run Postgres [at a DEBUG level](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/DevWikiGettingABackTrace) may be of help to identify what the code is doing, but without unit tests or documentation, this will be arduous.

Your (perhaps better) option is to contact the author listed in the header file, and see if he'd be willing to answer your question here -- the pgrouting folks explicitly [list this site](http://www.pgrouting.org/support.html) as the place to go for related issues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer all you questions, as I have no experience with DARP, but for the error log I would check /var/log/postgresql on debian/ubuntu, or whatever location you have set for logging:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that i've tried lots of configurations, but I can't see the messages logged from a C shared library like darp one.

Answer (score 0):

As scw said, you best chance will most likely be to contact the author directly. If you use [pgrouting mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/pgrouting-users) other users will probably be able to profit from your exchange.