# Is PgRouting DARP Function still being supported?

Tags: pgrouting

I'm asking this, because I need some tool to solve a DARP problem.

After researching I found PgRouting had included this functionality in one of its branches. But after installing it, getting stuck and looking for other people problems similar to mine it seems as if no one is answering DARP Releated questions. (Not just here but in general, PgRouting mailing list included)

Example: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18999/how-can-i-make-darp-function-of-pgrouting-working

And this one which has a year already hasn't been answered neither:
[Help making the DARP example run](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/help-making-the-darp-example-run) (I have the same doubts)

So finally my question is this functionality being supported? Is anyone working with it? or it has just being deprecated?